# App was disabled because of violating the Facebook Platform Policies (Platform Policy 8.1)

Tags: facebook

My app was disabled because of violating the Facebook Platform Policies (Platform Policy 8.1). 
But now I do not know to solve it and appeal. The app was disabled so I can not test login with this app.

I tried and not too much article talk about this kind of thing. I tried to appeal but no result. I tried to explain my difficult thing I got with FB dev via appeal message and waiting for feedback.

I do not know where to start. Could someone help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Did you try to do some research on the matter?

Comment: Yes, I tried and not too much article talk about this kind of thing. I tried to appeal but no result. I tried to explain my difficult thing I got with FB dev via appeal message and waiting for feedback

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's not a programming question at all.

Comment: @gp_sflover So you mean I should not ask this in StackOverflow?

Comment: @DuyVuongDao This is not a programming question, is it?

Comment: As a new user I want to encourage you to read the entire [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and in particular the Asking section to learn what you can ask and how to form a good and on-topic question on SO.

Comment: OK. Thanks all for your advice. I understood